# Using Euclid's Algorithm prove..

Tags: algorithms, congruences, number-systems

Using Euclid's Algorithm prove that the fraction $\frac{24n+5}{18n+4}$ is in lowest terms.

[image]

Is this solution going to be correct as a proof?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I think you missed a "${}+6n + 1$" in the first line, but otherwise this seems solid. I might have rewritten it for pure legibility, though; I find it slightly messy.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your equations aren't written correctly.

Should be $24n + 5 = 1 \times (18n + 4) + (6n + 1)$, and that the third equation is not neccesary. Other than that, it's correct.

Comment: Yes, I missed the term. It should be as you have written. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct after fixing the first equation. Another way is to eliminate $\,n\,$ by using $\,24/18 = \color{#0a0}4/\color{#c00}3\ $ so $\ \color{#0a0}4(18n\!+\!4)- \color{#c00}3(24n\!+\!5)=1\ $ yields the Bezout identity for the gcd.